# Vim: is there a way to persist the last edit?

Tags: repeated-commands

When you make a change, like <kbd>i</kbd>`foo`<kbd>ESC</kbd> to insert the text `foo`, this can, of course, be repeated using <kbd>.</kbd>.

However, if you quit Vim, in spite of Vim saving all sorts of state, including the contents of registers and per-file editing position and the `:` command history, this last edit seems to be lost. When you fire up Vim again, you cannot repeat the command.

Is there some trick to get that persisted into `.viminfo`, so we can type <kbd>i</kbd>`foo`<kbd>ESC</kbd>, then quit with <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>q</kbd><kbd>!</kbd>, up Vim again, and repeat the insert of `foo` with <kbd>.</kbd>?

Comment: It doesn't look like there's a way to do that... In fact, I don't think you can even inspect what the `.` command will do, since there's no register or function exporting that information... It might be a good idea to propose adding a function that exposes it (and maybe allows setting it?) though not sure it right now it's stored as a sequence of Vim commands, it might be stored in a different format inside Vim itself...

Comment: There is the dot register, I think, but it may be for something else (last inserted text?)